# Requesting yours to access GooglePlayServices

Tags: android, permissions, google-play-services

In my android application I wish to ask users permission to use the google playservices. Is there any way to do that?

Like for reading contacts, we use:

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                android.Manifest.permission.)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                    android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

                // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        }
```

P.S :  My gradle.build file has:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
```

Comment: "I wish to ask users permission to use the google playservices" -- you are welcome to display a dialog, asking the user if you should use Play Services. If the user says no, do not use the Play Services APIs in your app. However, unless they added this when I wasn't looking, Play Services does not have this feature built in. You would have to show your own dialog and track the user's choice yourself.

Comment: You don't need to ask permission to use Google Play Services as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google play service are library. You never need to ask for permission to use them. Bt depends on feature you wanna use u need permission.

Like to use map you need to ask location permission